# Исключить повторное нажатие inline кнопки в боте телеграм на aiogram

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

есть кнопка инлайн которая при нажатии запускает скрипт отправляющий сообщение, так вот иногда каким то образом пользователю удаётся нажать эту кнопку более одного раза, хотя после неё выполяется await call.answer()  await call.message.delete() , т.е сообщение с кнопкой удаляется.
не могу понять как это происходит и как это исключить. спасибо

Comment: Если допустим после нажатия кнопки, запускается сейчас скрипт, и ты просто убираешь эту самую кнопку? Получается что пользователь даже не сможет воспользоваться этой самой кнопкой.

Comment: нет, он пользуется ей один раз, она и предназначена для одного нажатия. но каким то образом у них иногда проскакивает 2-3 нажатия

Answer (score 0):

Используй машину состояний, после нажатия меня состояние и после первого нажатия программа не будет считывать повторное нажатие